# Syntax to create a Realm List

Tags: ios, database, list, swift2, realm

I'm using the Realm database (RealmSwift) and I want to add list values into my database. My first database is the Student database:

```
import Foundation
import RealmSwift

class Student: Object {

dynamic var identifier = ""
dynamic var name = ""
dynamic var university = ""
let subjects = List<Subjects>()  
override static func primaryKey() -> String? {
   return "identifier"
    }

  }
```

My subjects database would be simply:

```
import Foundation
import RealmSwift

class Subjects: Object {

dynamic var identifier = ""
dynamic var name = "" 

override static func primaryKey() -> String? {
   return "identifier"
    }

  }
```

Now, I'm unsure what correct syntax to use when creating a variable that contains list values.

```
  try! realm.write() {
let myStudent = realm.create(Student.self, value: ["identifier" : "1",    "name" : "James", "university" : "Stanford", "subjects" : "Engineering",  "Mathematics", "Physics"] )
```

realm.add(myStudent)

How could I also add in the identifier for each subject in my list?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you need to create the `Student` first with one dict, then create the `Subject`s one by one as Realm objects with separate dictionaries, and then add them to the parent `Student` as here:

```
let realm = try! Realm()

try! realm.write() {

  let studentDict = [
    "identifier" : "2",
    "name" : "James",
    "university" : "Stanford",
  ]


  let subjects = [
    [
      "name":"Misdirection",
      "identifier":"MS102"
    ],
    [
      "name":"Knitting",
      "identifier":"DDA201"
    ],
    [
      "name":"Levitation",
      "identifier":"HOP101",
    ]
  ]

  let myStudent = realm.create(Student.self,value:studentDict)


  for dict in subjects {
    let subj = realm.create(Subject.self,value:dict)
    myStudent.subjects.append(subj)
  }


  print("my student is \(myStudent)")

}
```

Output for me is:

```
my student is Student {
    identifier = 2;
    name = James;
    university = Stanford;
    subjects = RLMArray <0x7fd4d9d883a0> (
        [0] Subject {
            identifier = MS102;
            name = Misdirection;
        },
        [1] Subject {
            identifier = DDA201;
            name = Knitting;
        },
        [2] Subject {
            identifier = HOP101;
            name = Levitation;
        }
    );
}
```

Note this code will fail if run twice because Realm won't let you insert two `Students` with the same `identifier` value.

Comment: Perfect! I liked your "Levitation - HOP101"!

Answer (score 0):

You need to use an array, just like this:

```
let myStudent = realm.create(Student.self, value: ["identifier" : "1",    "name" : "James", "university" : "Stanford", "subjects" : ["Engineering",  "Mathematics", "Physics"] ] )
```

Comment: I'm getting a missing key error when I try that Ryniere.

Comment: I'm just wondering if I can use an identifier with lists. I hope so, I think I'll need an identifier.

Comment: Not sure it's Swift 2.0 - I'm using it and I get `Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'RLMException', reason: 'Invalid value 'Engineering' to initialize object of type 'Subject': missing key 'identifier''`,